# Getting a Path from an ImageIcon which is displayed on a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, file, path, imageicon

I am building a PhotoViewer. I want to be able to get the path of an ImageIcon which is displayed on a JLabel. Therefore I have created an MouseListener and a FileChooser. I have spent many hours trying to solve this issue.

```
for (int i=0; i< scaled.size(); i++){
labels.add(i, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(scaled.get(i))));
}
```

Here I want the give each Label which is beeing created a name i, so I can getName() later and ask the specific Label which ImageIcon it contains and its path.

I have three ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

ArrayList<ImageIcon> AL = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();

ArrayList<Image> scaled = new ArrayList<Image>();
```

Now the mouseClicked event should give me a Path to the ImageIcon on the Label which has been clicked.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(arg0.getSource().getName());
        int a = arg0.getSource().getName();
        getImageIcon.labels.get(a);
        CreateFrame(arg0.getSource().getDescription());
    }
```

After that a Frame is created with the Constructot parameter of the Path of the choosen picture. And I will display it in a seperate Frame.

Full Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageViewer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new ImageViewerFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Photoviewer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ImageViewerFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
    JLabel label;
    JFileChooser chooser;
    JMenuBar menubar;
    JMenu menu;
    JMenuItem menuitem;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();    

    public ArrayList<File> images = new ArrayList <File>();

    public void method1(){
        JLabel test = labels.get(0);
        System.out.println(test.getName());     
    }


    ArrayList<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

    ArrayList<ImageIcon> AL = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();

    ArrayList<Image> scaled = new ArrayList<Image>();

    public ImageViewerFrame() {
        setSize(500,500);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,5));
        label = new JLabel();
        add(label);
        add(panel);
        JButton test = new JButton ("TEST");
        test.addMouseListener(this);
        panel.add(test);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menubar);
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(menu);
        menuitem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        menu.add(menuitem);
        menuitem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

                        int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

                        if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                            File[] f = chooser.getSelectedFiles();

                            for(int i=0; i< f.length; i++)
                            {
                                images.add(f[i]);
                                ImageIcon imageicon = new ImageIcon(f[i].toString());
                                AL.add(imageicon);

                            }       

                            for (ImageIcon x : AL){
                                Image image = x.getImage();
                                Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(120,120, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                                scaled.add(newimg);
                            }               

                            for (int i=0; i< scaled.size(); i++){
                                labels.add(i, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(scaled.get(i))));
                            }

                            for (JLabel x : labels){
                                x.addMouseListener(ImageViewerFrame.this);
                            }

                            for (int i=0; i< scaled.size(); i++){
                                //panel.add(new JLabel(i), (new ImageIcon (scaled.get(i))));                        
                                panel.add(labels.get(i));

                            }
                                                                }
                                    }
                            });

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(arg0.getSource().getName());
        int a = arg0.getSource().getName();
        getImageIcon.labels.get(a);
        CreateFrame(arg0.getSource().getDescription());
    }

    private void CreateFrame() {
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Test");
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
        JButton next = new JButton("Next");
        JButton previous = new JButton ("Previous");
        JButton diashow = new JButton ("Diashow");
        panel3.add(next);
        panel3.add(previous);
        panel3.add(diashow);
        panel3.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        frame2.add(panel3);
    }



    private void CreateFrame(String s) {
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Test");
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
        JButton next = new JButton("Next");
        JButton previous = new JButton ("Previous");
        JButton diashow = new JButton ("Diashow");
        panel3.add(next);
        panel3.add(previous);
        panel3.add(diashow);
        panel3.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        frame2.add(panel3);
        panel3.add(new JLabel(s));

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: 1. what is the problem? 2. Why do you even need the path? You can just pass in the actual icon. If you need more help then post a proper [mcve]() that demonstrates the problem (not your application). So the `MCVE` will consist of a JFrame with a JLabel. You then add a MouseListener to the JLabel. All the other code is irrelevant to your stated problem.

Comment: The Problem is I cant get the Icon and I have scaled Images and full size images. If I click an ImageIcon (or better its Label) I want to get the full sizes image not the scaled one in order to display bigger.
So i figured I need to give each Label an Integer variable and have scaled and not scaled ArrayLists and then be able to get the full sized image.

Comment: You could use a `HashMap` to link the image to a file; you could use `JLabel#setName`/`JLabel#getName`; you could use `JLabel#putClientProperty`/`JLabel#getClientProperty`

Comment: I will try to remove as much code which is not relevant to the question but I apprehend the problems goes a bit further and I am not able to Minimalize since this is surely not a simple Syntax Error

Comment: @MadProgrammer I will read up on HashMaps, sounds like it might help thanks!

Comment: When you scale the Image you can easily create the ImageIcon using the scaled image and then set the description of the ImageIcon to be the path of the original image. Then when you click on the label you get the ImageIcon from the label and the path from the description. There is no need for multiple arrays or anything fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple possible approaches to this, none of which involve:

> Getting a Path from an ImageIcon..

See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

One way:

```
File[] f = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
```

Declare `File[] f` as an attribute of the class, so it is accessible later. On click, find the source component, get the image icon, and get the image from it.

```
JLabel label = (JLabel)mouseEvent.getSource();
ImageIcon imageIcon = (ImageIcon)label.getIcon();
Image img = imageIcon.getImage();
```

Then:

```
int index = scaled.get(img);
```

& the file is:

```
File file = f[index];
```